# Conversion between Bigarray kinds

Tags: ocaml

Considering those 3 bigarrays:

```
open Bigarray
let arr_float32 = Array1.of_array Float32 c_layout [|42.0|]
let arr_uint8 = Array1.of_arrayInt8_unsigned c_layout [|42|]
let arr_float32_as_uint8 = Array1.of_array Int8_unsigned c_layout [|0; 0; 40; 66|]
```

1. Is there a way of casting `arr_float32` to make it equal (in type and in value) to `arr_uint8`?
2. Is there a way of reinterpreting `arr_float32` to make it equal (in type and value) to `arr_float32_as_uint8`?

---

`[|0; 0; 40; 66|]` being the little endian representation of `42.0`

Answer (score 0):

The normal meaning of a cast (IMHO) is to produce a new value, not to change the value of something. In other words, your first question just asks if there's a way to compute this new bigarray. There is a way to compute it by creating a new bigarray and using `int_of_float` on each element of the original array.

There's no way to reinterpret the values in a bigarray (or any values in OCaml, really) without going outside the language to pierce the abstraction.

Comment: Since the `Bigarray` lib provides functions to reinterpret from `Genarray`/`Array1`/... and to reinterpret the `layout`, I was hopping for a clean solution implemented in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the type of a value. That's something that really isn't allowed by the type system. The type system is there specifically so you can't do this (accidentally).

None the less sometimes there are reasons why one must. Usually for performance. The function to do this is `Obj.magic : 'a -> 'b`. As the type shows Obj.magic takes any type and outputs any other type. It changes type as if by magic. :)

One should only do so in precisely controlled situations. You must know what you are doing and that it's OK to do so when using Obj.magic. It's best to annotate the types around Obj.magic as explicitly as possible so you don't get any random results. In your case specify the type for the input and output Bigarrays.

Bigarrays internally are just a blob of memory with some reference counting for the slicing operations. There is some compiler magic going on for the get/set methods that optimize depending on the type of the array. As such access to the array must be properly aligned to the type you access. For example don't try to get the subarray at offset 1 of a int8 array and access it as floats. That will fail on many CPUs. But using them straight up should work.

Let me repeat it: Beware that you are doing something to circumvent the type system. Obj.magic makes no checks at all that you are doing anything sane. It's your job to know what you are doing there. I've cast Bigarrays using Obj.magic before and I believe it's safe to do so. If I'm wrong then it should crash quickly as Obj.magic usually doesn't survive misuse.